# ISNULL() in RowFilter not the same as in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

In a code i'm maintaining, I saw we were getting a DataView, then apply a RowFilter to it example:

```
dv.RowFilter = "IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') = 'NULL'";
```

This returns all records with LOAN_STATUS is NULL in the DB.

I figured I would move the condition to SQL and added in the equivalent WHERE clause:

```
WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') = 'NULL'
```

However, my SQL this time did not return me anything. It will work with

```
WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND LOAN_STATUS IS NULL
```

I did some more test :
Using RowFilter, Both yields the same records effectively IsNull() is the same as IS NULL

```
dv.RowFilter = "IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') = 'NULL'";
```

vs

```
dv.RowFilter = "LOAN_STATUS IS NULL";
```

However, using strictly SQL, the 1st one returned no records

```
WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') = 'NULL'
```

vs

```
WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND LOAN_STATUS IS NULL
```

Can anyone tell me if it is normal and explain to me the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 1):

> WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') =
>   'NULL'
>
> vs
>
> WHERE [Other existing conditions] AND LOAN_STATU IS NULL

You are checking two different fields, the first is checking `LOAN_STATUS` the 2nd is checking `LOAN_STATU`

The following two statements

`ISNULL(Field,Constant) = Constant` and `Field IS NULL` are functionally the same for all values of Field not equal to Constant in TSQL

Another possible reason you are seeing the result you are seeing is if the ODBC system is creating the null values.

Comment: Sorry I made a type LOAN_STATU should be LOAN_STATUS... so both WHERE Clause is checking for nulls in the same field called LOAN_STATUS

Answer (score -1):

What you posted: `dv.RowFilter = "IsNull(LOAN_STATUS, 'NULL') = 'NULL'"`

Says if the LOAN_STATUS is null assign the value null and then check if it is null,
to me looks very odd.

`ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )` checks an expression and if it is null it replaces the expression with `replacement_value`.

See BOL for more details or this link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

IS NULL checks if the condition is null, it has no intentions of replacing the value.  If you are talking TSQL and you want to check if a value is NULL use `WHERE MyField IS NULL` or `MyField IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I understand the replacement in ISNULL() function vs checking directly if the Field IS NULL. What I can't understand why it behaves the same in RowFilter - effectively returning all records with NULL values using either way... whereas in the SQL WHERE, using both ISNULL() vs IS NULL does not behave the same?